# VS code extension not allowing me to use 'child_process' module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, esbuild

I am creating a VS code extension, and it will need to execute shell commands. My understanding is I can use the child_process module to do this in JavaScript.

Context: I am new to TS/JS. The project is in TypeScript, and I use esbuild.js (not sure what this does?).

So it compiles perfectly fine, but once I run the actual extension in VS code and check the developer tools, I see the following error:

```
index.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "child_process". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I was trying to import like so:

```
import * as cp from 'child_process';

cp.exec(blah, blah)
```

Here is my esbuild.js:

```
const { build } = require("esbuild");

const baseConfig = {
    bundle: true,
    minify: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    sourcemap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
    platform: "node"
};

const extensionConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    platform: "node",
    mainFields: ["module", "main"],
    format: "cjs",
    entryPoints: ["./src/extension.ts"],
    outfile: "./out/extension.js",
    external: ["vscode"],
};

(async () => {
    try {
        await build(extensionConfig);
        console.log("build complete");
    } catch (err) {
        process.stderr.write(err.stderr);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();

const watchConfig = {
    watch: {
        onRebuild(error, result) {
            console.log("[watch] build started");
            if (error) {
                error.errors.forEach(error =>
                    console.error(`> ${error.location.file}:${error.location.line}:${error.location.column}: error: ${error.text}`)
                );
            } else {
                console.log("[watch] build finished");
            }
        },
    },
};

(async () => {
    const args = process.argv.slice(2);
    try {
        if (args.includes("--watch")) {
            // Build and watch source code
            console.log("[watch] build started");
            await build({
                ...extensionConfig,
                ...watchConfig,
            });
            console.log("[watch] build finished");
        } else {
            // Build source code
            await build(extensionConfig);
            console.log("build complete");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        process.stderr.write(err.stderr);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();

const webviewConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    target: "es2020",
    format: "esm",
    entryPoints: ["./src/webview/main.ts"],
    outfile: "./out/webview.js",
};

const mainWebviewConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    target: "es2020",
    format: "esm",
    entryPoints: ["./src/webview/mainWebView.ts"],
    outfile: "./out/mainwebview.js",
};

(async () => {
    const args = process.argv.slice(2);
    try {
        if (args.includes("--watch")) {
            // Build and watch extension and webview code
            console.log("[watch] build started");
            await build({
                ...extensionConfig,
                ...watchConfig,
            });
            await build({
                ...webviewConfig,
                ...watchConfig,
            });
            console.log("[watch] build finished");
        } else {
            // Build extension and webview code
            await build(extensionConfig);
            await build(webviewConfig);
            console.log("build complete");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        process.stderr.write(err.stderr);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();

(async () => {
    const args = process.argv.slice(2);
    try {
        if (args.includes("--watch")) {
            // Build and watch extension and webview code
            console.log("[watch] build started");
            await build({
                ...extensionConfig,
                ...watchConfig,
            });
            await build({
                ...mainWebviewConfig,
                ...watchConfig,
            });
            console.log("[watch] build finished");
        } else {
            // Build extension and webview code
            await build(extensionConfig);
            await build(mainWebviewConfig);
            console.log("build complete");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        process.stderr.write(err.stderr);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();
```

And here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2020",
        "lib": ["es2020", "DOM"],
        "outDir": "out",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "rootDir": "src"
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", ".vscode-test"]
}
```

Finally, here is the relevant dependencies from package.json and my scripts:

```
"scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "npm run package",
        "compile": "node ./esbuild.js",
        "package": "NODE_ENV=production node ./esbuild.js",
        "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
        "watch": "node ./esbuild.js --watch"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^20.11.5",
        "@types/vscode": "^1.73.0",
        "@types/vscode-webview": "^1.57.4",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.0",
        "esbuild": "^0.16.17",
        "eslint": "^8.32.0",
        "typescript": "^5.3.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@vscode/webview-ui-toolkit": "^1.4.0"
    }
```

This is a VS code extension so I'm not sure if the environment allows child_process, but from my reading online, it seems it should, so I'm unsure why I am seeing this error.

Comment: how are you running/debugging?

Comment: Try changing your compiler option in tsconfig.json from `"module": "commonjs",` to `"module": "Node16",` (that's what I have), although that may break your other js. CommonJS will work with `require()` but not  with `import`. You may want to start a new project calling `npx --package yo --package generator-code -- yo code` and comparing configurations or trying the simplest code on the new one and see if it works.